# How to get ListView.SubItems

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I'm trying to make a program that inputs text into a document depending on the user input, and I am currently displaying it as a ListView.

I can't figure out how to get the SubItem from the item, as this is my current code.

```vb
For Each item In ListView1.Items
    Dim inputString72 As String = "@bot.command()" + vbNewLine
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(
      SaveFileDialog1.FileName, inputString72, True)
    Dim inputString73 As String = "async def " + item.Text + "(ctx):" + vbNewLine
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(
      SaveFileDialog1.FileName, inputString73, True)
    Dim inputString74 As String = "    await ctx.send('" + THE SUBITEM OF THE ITEM GOES HERE + "')" + vbNewLine
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(
      SaveFileDialog1.FileName, inputString74, True)
Next
```

Comment: *"I can't figure out how to get the SubItem from the item"*. How is that possible when the item has a `SubItems` property?

Comment: Is there only a single subitem?

Comment: Sorry, I gave you a c# example by mistake.  You could replace the placeholder with something like: `Dim inputString74 As String = "    await ctx.send('" + String.Join(" ", item.SubItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem).Select(Function(x) x.Text)) + "')" + vbNewLine` if you need the texts of the SubItems separated by white spaces. Change the separator as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more efficient to use the .net File class. No need to call the method several times in each iteration. From the docs. "The WriteAllText method opens a file, writes to it, and then closes it. " That is a lot of openning and closing. Build a string with a `StringBuilder` (which is mutable) and then write once to the file.

I used interpolated strings (it is preceded by a $) which allows you to put a variable directly in a string surrounded by braces.

`SubItem` indexes start at 0 with the first column. The `.Text` property of the `SubItem` will return its contents.

```
Private Sub WriteListViewToFile(FilePath As String)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        sb.AppendLine("@bot.command()")
        sb.AppendLine($"async def {item.Text}(ctx):")
        sb.AppendLine($"    await ctx.send('{item.SubItems(1).Text}')")
    Next
    File.WriteAllText(FilePath, sb.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        WriteListViewToFile(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```